# Phoenix Caches Indefinitely

Tags: caching, vagrant, virtual-machine, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm writing a project with a lot of static files

Whenever I change a custom.js file, even thought it get changed both in
`web/static/assets/custom.js` and `priv/static/assets/custom.js`

When I try to reach the resource I get the old version, which is also most of the times corrupted

[image]

I tried:

- restarting the server
- running `brunch build`
- removing the whole `_build` directory
- changing the files further
- clearing browsers cache
- using `url localhost:4000/assets/js/custom.js -H 'Pragma: no-cache'`

Still the server serves old file

#### Edit

It seems to be an issue with `mtime` difference between vagrant VM and host.

So the real question is:
How to eliminate that issue?

Comment: Try removing the file outright.  If it's really picking up the version you think it is you should get an error.  If it's pointed to a different location--no error and you confirm it's pointed to a different file.

Comment: Since this is a JS issue, you're most likely experiencing a node issue. Perhaps `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same behavior (on a VM too) for my js/css files.